# Magento CE 1.7 - Front end not loading?

Tags: magento-1.7

Having a problem with our store now for over 1 hour. We have access to backend, but our whole front end has gone down. We've made no changes to anything,

Does anyone know of any common errors which could cause this on Magento CE 1.7

website is www.bellydeluxe.de

Comment: Try https://kb.magenting.com/content/22/38/en/magento-shows-blank-empty-page-how-do-i-solve-this.html

Comment: Add this line in your root index.php and check the error :: error_reporting(1);

Comment: I tried this, both methods - and neither are displaying anything. The backend is loading no problem, and i'm getting no information from any logs whatsoever?

Comment: @Phil did you tried [this](https://www.magmodules.eu/help/general/magento-whitescreen-backend)

Comment: Thanks, I've tried all the steps mentioned and unfortunately nothing is working or helping. I do not know what has caused this. We didn't install any new extensions, no changes have been made to code both in front or back end, no adjustments or themes have been added, literally nothing was going on during the time that this problem occurred. I have contacted our provider, they've now spend 2 hours searching for the issue but are unable to locate it. Is there any common issues known with this version of magento that could trigger this event?

Comment: You have to find at least some error. Pl check console for any js error OR you can check with disable some module one by one.

Comment: @Phil do you have latest backups ?

Comment: We have backups performed at 11:59:59PM every night and this is something we can recover from however, as we have a large amount of orders each day - we will lose a large range of orders from today.

Comment: @Phil thats true, its not a big deal to solve, i hope you guys set email address in backend that every order information will go that email id, you can take this as last option. so that all order information will be available in email....

Comment: @Phil i got that no changes has done from past one hour, but try disabling 3rd party modules  through app/etc/local.xml file and check once

Comment: @Baby in Magento,

I tried the XML like you said, still - nothing works. Email from Magento to Address failed as no response could be gained from the server to the client, which makes me think something is wrong serverside.

Comment: @Phil when is last mail in email inbox , also any idea when site got latest order , is all recent order related mails are present in inbox ? there may be much chances in code issue than serverside.  but you can cross check with server team.

Comment: @Phil do you guys use `git or svn` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Different methods which might help to solve front end error.**

Enable developer mode in `index.php`.

Next check `var/log/system.log` and `var/log/exception.log`. You can double check via the database by looking at `core_config` and finding the logging values under the `path`:  `dev/log/active`. If it is set to to `0` set it to `1` to enable.

If Magento is not displaying or logging anything, then take a look at your web servers error.log file, as it will offer the most insight, if an exception is occuring above magento. You'll also want to double check your `.htaccess` and web server configuration for the domain.

There also may be a module or some custom code outputting (echo/print/debug/etc.) before hand, causing the error returned.

Even try to disable compiler

rename local.xml.sample to local.xml at yourmagentodir/errors/ for print the error

Comment: Unfortunately, I only have limited access to the server here. I've checked the logs and nothing has been added since 2014. So nothing new to report from that section.

Comment: I suggest renaming local.xml.sample to local.xml at yourmagentodir/errors/ for print the error

Comment: Just tried this and still no reporting or anything coming up. Could it be that there is something wrong with PhpMyAdmin?